# What's an issue with this query

Tags: mysql

Following is my query in which I am making insertion in one table and some specific values from another table. Kindly let me know what is an appropriate way to write such a query. Thank,

```
Insert into c_table (name,number,class) 
values ('1','2',select count(id) from thetable)
```

Comment: Are there any examples out there of using SELECT in conjunction with INSERT, or are we breaking new groud here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close, but try enclosing your subquery in parentheses:

```
insert into c_table (name,number,class) 
values ('1','2',(select count(id) from thetable))
```

Comment: Very Close to be CLOSED DOWN  you mean

Comment: @NullSoulException The query he mentioned actually worked. What's the issue with this query?

Comment: @user3027531 Doesn't seem like the right form to recommend, since as soon as you change that subquery such that it returns more than one row, what will MySQL say? I know it likes cowboy-style group by, but I'm not sure if it will like cowboy-style subqueries.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I never heard of "cowboy-style `GROUP BY`" but that has to be the perfect term to describe MySQL's lenience in `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of a `VALUES()` clause, use the `INSERT INTO ...SELECT` pattern with static values for the first two columns in the `SELECT` component.  The values of the first two pseudo-columns in the `SELECT` list will always be the same, but the value for the `COUNT()` will change dynamically with `thetable.`  Be sure to add a `WHERE` clause to the `SELECT` statement if necessary.

```
INSERT INTO c_table (name, number, class)
  SELECT
    '1' AS name,
    '2' AS number,
    COUNT(id) AS class
  FROM thetable
 /* WHERE <conditions if necessary> */
```